# Align Active Camera to View - Not working

Tags: 3d-view, camera

**Align Active Camera to View**

I used to do use this command all the time in 2.79. Now in 2.8 it's not working anymore - greyed out in the menu.

[image]

**Why might this be?**

For anyone who doesn't know - this operation is useful because you can use the Viewport to approximate what you want framed in the shot, then place the active Camera there (as a starting point before fine-tuning its position). I mean, *was* useful when it still worked.

Additional info - camera settings:

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you actually have a camera set as active in your scene ?

Comment: @Gorgious Yes, I do. It shows up in my Outliner, and in the Viewport. When I press `0` I enter the Camera View. I can render and everything... everything except align the camera to my view in the Viewport.

Comment: Weird. In your scene properties, is the "Camera" field empty ? Might be a bug. Are you using the latest stable 2.90 ?

Comment: @Gorgious I just added a screenshot of my camera settings to my post. Pretty standard. Yes, my build is the current stable 2.90.0 to be precise.

Comment: @Gorgious I just discovered that if I Load Factory Settings it works again. But I've already started customizing a lot of my settings and shortcuts and I don't want to lose those. So hopefully there is some way to resolve this without wiping everything.

Comment: @Gorgious Your first intuition was correct! I did not know it was possible to have a camera not be the Active one when it's the only one in the Scene - but apparently it is! I just posted an answer with details. Thanks for the hint that led me to try designating what I *thought* had already been designated, and ultimately solved the problem!

Comment: Glad you sorted it out :)

Comment: I had the same problem and the only solution was to delete the camera and create a new one. Nothing logical worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The camera was behaving like the Active Camera (possibly because it was the only one in the scene), but technically it was *not* the Active Camera.

Selecting the camera object and specifying this resolved the issue.

[image]